# three.js: make texture zero outside boundaries

Tags: javascript, three.js

Currently there are 3 wrapping modes in three.js:

```
THREE.RepeatWrapping
THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping
THREE.MirroredRepeatWrapping
```

Example:

```
var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( "textures/water.jpg" );
texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
```

I'm using textures in shaders to do gpgpu computing and for my purpose I would like the texture to be zero outside its bounds. If you use ClampToEdge for example, looking up values outside the texture bounds will yield the color of the nearest pixel that is inside the bounds. Looking up a value at coordinates (1.3, .5) will give the color at (1., .5) since 1.3 is too large for texture coordinates

So I want this to yield zero outside the bounds, or if that is not possible I want to be able to continously set the edge to zero. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: I may be misunderstanding, but don't you already know it is out of bounds at 1.3 and can then just test if it is in bounds and return / set 0 if not?.

Answer (score 2):

In your shader check the texture coordinates

```
vec4 value = vec4(0);
if (texcoord.x >= 0. || texcoord.x <= 1. ||     
    texcoord.y >= 0. || texcoord.y <= 1.) 
  value = texture2D(someSampler, texcoord);
}
```